# I would like to check if the comparison operator is true or false

Tags: sorting, haskell

So I know how to write a code to see if my list is sorted from smallest to biggest

```
isSorted :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Bool
isSorted []       = True
isSorted [x]      = True
isSorted (x:y:xs) = x <= y && isSorted (y:xs)
```

But I would like to write a code that tells me if my list is sorted by the given comparison operator
for example 
I wanna put in

```
sorted (<=) [1,2,2,4,5] == True
sorted (<)  [1,2,2,4,5] == False
sorted (==) [1,2,2,2,3] == False
```

What would I have to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to write a code that tells me if my list is sorted by the given comparison operator for example I wanna put in

`isSorted` function can be enhanced to receive a function, which compares two elements and that function can be called instead of `<=` in your example:

```
isSorted :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
isSorted _ []       = True
isSorted _ [x]      = True
isSorted comparator (x:y:xs) = comparator x y && isSorted comparator (y:xs)
```

So the function is going to be called as:

```
isSorted (<) [1, 2, 3]
isSorted (>=) [3, 2, 1]
```

Calling it with `(==)` will just compare if the elements are the same in the list.

Comment: Why do you have an `Ord` constraint? EDIT: `isSorted` could also be called `pairwiseCompare` with an alternate implementation of `pC f xs = all (uncurry f) (zip xs (drop 1 xs))`

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I think I understand where you driving at, I just wanted to illustrate that specific example, which receives comparator and checks, whether a list, that can be ordered, is actually sorted. But yea, the function can be generalised and answer whether every consecutive pair satisfy a certain condition

Answer (score 1):

The idea can be to *parameterize* the comparison. Now you use `<=`, but we can replace it with an `f`, we pass as a parameter:

```
isSorted :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
isSorted _ [] = True
isSorted _ [x] = True
isSorted f (x:y:xs) = f x y && isSorted f (y:xs)
```

We can however improve the following code by using [**`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) and [**`and :: [Bool] -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:and):

```
isSorted :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
isSorted _ [] = True
isSorted f xs@(_:xs2) = and(zipWith f xs xs2)
```

The `isSorted` thus takes a predicate that works with two `a`s, and we check if the predicate holds for every item, and its next item. You can thus write more advanced predicates that do not necessary encapsulate an *order relation*.

Comment: @molbdnilo: aarrgh, yes. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: @molbdnilo: yes, since this was mentioned just above the code fragment :)

Comment: Not necessarily an improvement, but as an example of reasoning with laziness: the `isSorted _ []` clause can be removed using `isSorted f xs = and $ zipWith f xs $ tail xs`, since `and []` = `True` and if `xs` is empty then `tail xs` will never be called by `zipWith`; it can also be written equivalently as a lazy pattern match `isSorted f xs@ ~(_:xs') = and $ zipWith f xs xs'`, but it’s a bit more syntactically noisy.